# Selenium - page load timeout

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2

Is it possible to set timeout for page load in Selenium test?

I have a problem, when sometimes test execution freezes on page load (application doesn't load new page, test hangs up), so test needs to be killed manually - this wouldn't be a problem if I would run only one test on nightly bases.

As I understand `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()` only works on `driver.get(URL)` method - it doesn't work when Selenium clicks buttons and links during test execution. Is this correct? How can I manage time of wait for every page load?

Comment: Does this old question help ? http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/what-is-seleniums-default-timeout-for-page-loading

Comment: Phil, it doesnt

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that `Click()` will not wait for a page load, so the page load timeout does not apply. I follow clicks with a wait for some element that I know will be on the page that is loading. You can setup an implicit timeout

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```

and then simply try to find the appropriate element

```
link.Click();

// implicit timeout
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'alert-error')] | //ul[id('menu')]"));
```

or use an explicit timeout/wait. Note that the implicit timeout still affects this code, so any explicit timeouts should be longer than the implicit setting otherwise they won't really do anything.

```
link.Click();

// explicit timeout
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
var element = wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'alert-error')] | //ul[id('menu')]")));
```