# Working of pageloadTimeout in selenium webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

How does pageload timeout in selenium webdriver work? Once set using

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()
```

what is lifetime of the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `driver.manage().timeouts()` value lives till the instance of the driver is alive, be it the default value or a custom value set by the user.

So to answer your question- Once you set a `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()` value it will remain constant throughout the lifetime of your driver instance. If you want to change the value you will have to reset it.
Brief explanations on the waits [here](http://assertselenium.com/2013/01/29/webdriver-wait-commands/).

Answer (score 0):

The default `pageLoadTimeout()` is a member of `Timeouts` interface which is set to never in wevdriver according to [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/what-is-seleniums-default-timeout-for-page-loading). But, it is possible to overwrite. See [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html)

Comment: yeah, but my question was different. If i set pageLoadTimeout to a value, is it set for lifetime of driver instance or just next command?